# DAO class instance vs DAO EJB

Tags: java, ejb

What is the best practice in java EE?

1. Create an instance of the DAO class in the service (or manager) class

   SalesDAO salesDao = new SalesDAOImpl();

   salesDao.findCustomers();

or

2. Call a DAO EJB in the service (or manager) class

   @EJB
   private SalesDAO salesDao;

   salesDao.findCustomers();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is the best practice (your DAO could be a CDI bean: it doesn't have to be an EJB).

Dependency injection is what makes the code testable: you can inject a mock DAO in the service when unit-testing the service.

BTW, the DAO will also need to have a DataSource or an EntityManager injected to be able to get data from the database. This is only possible if the DAO instance is managed by the container.

Comment: How can I do that using a CDI Bean? You told me that it doesn't have to be an EJB

Comment: `@Inject private SalesDAO salesDao;`

Comment: I get a NullPointer Exception when I try to use the salesDao class. Do I need to put some annotation to the Dao interface?

Comment: No. But you need to have CDI activated. Depending on the version, it needs a beans.xml file (even empty) in the META-INF directory of the jar.

Answer (score 2):

I preffer the second one.
DAO talks about responsability, means manage persistent data. But there is no reason for not to use a EJB. Let the container manage instances for you.

Adam Bien, member of  EJB 3.1 spec comitee said in his blog:
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/generic_crud_service_aka_dao